# Using gitstats on a linux terminal

Tags: linux, git, terminal, statistics, command

So one of my friend told my about this gitstats command that shows you stats about commits, lines writted, dates, ect. of an actual git repo. The thing is, he's using it with is windows command prompt and I'm using a Linux terminal (with Ubuntu) that contains git. I've installed gitstats with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gitstats
```

The problem is that I didn't find a way to get stats or a graphic like this one:

[image]

I want to know if it's even possible to do this on a Linux terminal and if yes, what command should I type so I can have something like on the picture.

Thank you !

EDIT : This is the link that guided me to install 
[gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'm not a user of `git-stats`, but the image you posted contains the commands used. Have you used e.g. `git-stats -l`? What does the output look like? How does it differ from the image you posted?

Comment: Adding to what Kevin points out, the screenshot you showed is most definitely NOT a windows command prompt.  It looks to be a MacOS terminal window which, as one would expect for modern MacOS, is running a unix-style shell.  I am aware of no reason Ubuntu would behave differently from this, so if it is behaving differently then more detail is needed in the question.

Comment: `git-stats` seems to be different from `gitstats`. With your favourite search engine you could search for the command `"git-stats"` you see in your image. Use quotes to search for exactly this string. This will probably lead you to https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats

Comment: Yes, I've writted what's on the picture, and it didn't do anything. The thing is, gitstats and git-stats are two different things. You can't install git-stats on the linux terminal, but my question in other words, is there a way to do what git-stats does if I'm using gitstats ?